¿Qué significa la frase hecha "dar cera"?
¿La frase hecha "dar cera" a alguien, qué quiere decir?

Se usa en contexto coloquial.

Ejemplo:

"Los amigos dan cera a Manolo, porque Manolo había hecho planes
con su novia"

En este vídeo se usa entre los segundos 0:22 y 0:28.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=88SJcPAqc_I&t=22s



No la he encontrado en el diccionario de la RAE

La acepción de cera que buscas sí se encuentra recogida en el DRAE


f. coloq. Esp. Agresión, ataque físico o verbal.


Al igual que una paliza o ataque físico se da, también se da cera, que puede asimilarse tanto a ataque físico como verbal. Los amigos de Manolo le dieron cera - se metieron con él por calzonazos, se rieron de él, lo chincharon - porque los dejó tirados para irse con su novia.

Cierto! Pensaba que "dar cera" aparecería tras todas las acepciones, abajo de todo como locución o expresión. Allí aparece por ejemplo "hacer de alguien cera y pabilo"

@tremendows Sí, yo también esperaba ver la expresión ahí. Cosas del DRAE.


Cualquiera de estas expresiones populares significan golpear, comportándose o tratando a alguien de forma ruda o violenta. Ejemplos: "El partido iba bien hasta que lo contrarios comenzaron a dar caña"; "Es temible como da cera ese boxeador", "Los dos grupos comenzaron a calentarse y de pronto se pusieron a repartir estopa entre ellos", "Si no entiende la lección hay que darle leña al mono hasta que aprenda".

Fuente
Dar cera es lo mismo que dar la paliza, dar  la tabarra, dar la brasa esto en argot significa ponerse pesados o "castigar" con un mismo tema sin parar. El porque se utiliza la palabra cera lo explica el mismo enlace:

...la  cera (materia usada para suplicios, al ser vertida hirviendo sobre las llagas hechas por los latigazos).

